# Are these interpreted the same way in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, express

I was wondering if these two ways to write this are interpreted the same by Node/Express:

```
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.methodOverride());
```

vs

```
app
  .use(express.bodyParser())
  .use(express.logger('dev'))
  .use(express.methodOverride());
```

I think the later looks cleaner, but I was wondering if this will still be asynchronous.

Comment: Express supports chaining, so these are equivalent.

Comment: `app.use` doesn't do anything asynchronously.  It just sets up the middleware that will be called later when a request comes in, and that middleware may call asynchronous functions so that the single Node thread isn't blocked from handling other requests while work is being performed.